# ios navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have this buttons controller with buttons xib. This buttons is included in my other views. The problem I have is button clicked navigation.

```
-(IBAction) gotoReport:(id) sender
{   NSLog(@"ll");
    ReportStepOne *report = [[ReportStepOne alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:report animated:YES];
    [report release];
}
```

I could see the log message, but navigation doesn't work. I guess I should not use self?

appDelegate.H

```
UINavigationController *navCon;
```

appDelegate.M

```
navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navCon setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];
    [navCon pushViewController:login animated:NO];
    [login release];
    [window addSubview:navCon.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example of `IBAction` is correct, it should pus the view. If it's not pushing, you need to check your XIB to make sure you have connected the correct button to this `IBAction`.

Answer (score 0):

in your app delegate, do this instead:

```
Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];

// Make navController a property..
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login];

//This is the key..
[[self window] setRootViewController:self.navController];
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

[login release];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```