# Showing the UINavigationController and the back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am having an issue which I am not able to solve and I am sure that the solution is very simple.

I define a `UINavigation controller` in my `AppDelegate` and show the `navigation bar` on top of the main `ViewController` with the App name as title .

This `ViewController` calls a `tableview` linked to a `CoreData database` at some point as follows:

```
MyView *tbl = [[MyView alloc] init];



tbl.delegate = self;

(...)

MyAppDelegate *app = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    


app.itbl = tbl;
[app.navnav pushViewController:app.itbl animated:YES];  //Should not this one make the
```

`navigation bar` and  the back button be visible?

MyView is a class that manipulates the `coredata` and puts it in the `tableview`.  My issue is that the `UINavigation` bar does not appear on the new `ViewController` and so there is no back button. (By the way, I do not use the hidden property of the `Navigationbar` at all).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of navigation controller is incorrect... The code you used will create a seperate navigation controller in viewcontroller and table controller

Please read the following discussions before you proceed

http://www.idev101.com/learn/navigation_controllers.html

[ios navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473495/ios-navigation-controller)

[Navigation Back Button does not show,how to add back button to UINavigationItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670994/navigation-back-button-does-not-show-how-to-add-back-button-to-uinavigationitem)